# Рекурсивно выполнять функцию

Tags: php

На сервере имеется директория, в которую вложены другие папки с цифровыми наименованиями.

Я с хочу создать в папке новую директорию, для этого использую простой рэндом:

```
$randval = rand(1, 1000); // Беру число в нужном диапазоне
$structure = '../objects/'.$randval.'/'; 
if (!mkdir($structure, 0777, true)) {   // создаю папку
die('Не удалось создать директорию...'); }
```

Всё здесь хорошо, кроме того, что число может совпасть. Поэтому я думаю после получения числа проверить, нет ли уже на сервере такой папки. Делаю это следующим образом:

```
  if(file_exists("../objects/$randval"))  // Проверяем, что на сервере есть папка с таким ID
  {  
     if(is_dir("../objects/$randval")) 
     { echo 'Такая папка уже существует!'; }}
```

Далее у меня начинаются проблемы - моих познаний недостаточно, чтобы построить следующую структуру работы скрипта:

1. Выбрать число.
2. Проверить, если такая папка на сервере, если нет, то создать папку, если есть, то снова выбрать число и так далее.

Может кто-нибудь направить на путь истинный?

Comment: Берите не рандом, а время в виде timestamp. А ещё лучше timestamp + microtime(), и тогда ваши проверки будут не нужны.

Comment: Время в виде timestamp или строка - слишком длинно выходит...

Comment: @febick29 - вы думаете, ваши велосипеды с рекурсивным обходом и проверками проще, чем длинное уникальное(!) имя объекта? пффф...

Comment: Дело в том, что потом я использую название папки, передавая его через GET запрос, и число из четырех или пяти символов в адресной строке мне нравится больше, чем длинное уникальное неизвестно что)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зачем вам случайность – может, лучше последовательный перебор?

```
$range = 1000; // макс. значение

// см. http://php.net/sprintf
// вместо %04d встанет число, добитое нулями до 4 символов
// формат, с 0 до длины $range. Напр. вместо "25" будет "0025"
$format = "../objects/%0".strlen($range)."d/";

$found = FALSE;
for( $i=0; $i<$range; $i++){
    $structure = sprintf( $format, $i);
    if( file_exists( $structure)) continue;

    // нашли несуществующую папку!
    $found = TRUE;
    break;
}

if (!$found)  die('Все '.$range.' папок уже созданы, не впихнуть!');
if (!mkdir($structure, 0777, true))  die('Не удалось создать директорию...');

// мы молодцы, есть свежая папка $structure
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать сделать так!)

Answer (score 1):

В Вашем варианте, может оказаться, например, 1000 папок, и если рекурсивно пытаться постоянно выбрать число - может произойти бесконечная рекурсия. Почему просто не давать папкам имена по количеству файлов в папке - 2? (.. и .) `count(scandir($dir)) - 2`.

Ответов на Ваш вопрос может быть несколько, например, рекурсивный выбор:

```
function createRandomDir($count = 0, $maxCount = 777) 
{
    if(++$count > $maxCount) //предотвращение бесконечной рекурсии
         exit('Не удалось создать директорию... Предотвращена бесконечная рекурсия');

    $randval = rand(1, 1000); // Беру число в нужном диапазоне
    $structure = '../objects/'.$randval.'/';

    if(is_dir("../objects/$randval")) 
        createRandomDir() //рекурсивный вызов, будет создано новое число, которое ВОЗМОЖНО не совпадет с именем существующей папки

    if (!mkdir($structure, 0777, true)) // создаю папку
        exit('Не удалось создать директорию...');
}
```

Или можно зациклить `$i` от 0 до 1000, проверять наличие папки `$i+$randVal`, если `$i+$randVal > 1000` - обнулить `$i` и `$randVal`, если цикл завершен (`$i>1000`), а папка не создана - нет свободных названий в множестве от 0 до 1000.

Еще можно посмотреть функции `uniqid()` (возвращает строку, а не число), или `str_replace('.', '', microtime(true))`, если нужно именно число, но оно будет больше 1000.

Comment: В каждой папке одинаковое количество файлов, поэтому этот метод не очень подойдёт...

 Больше тысячи папок не предполагается, поэтому я ограничился этим числом, но моно наверное использовать до десяти тысяч - что бы наверняка.

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, использование rand() вполне уместно для описанной задачи. Если бы ТС не упоминал, что ему не нравятся длинные папки, то я бы предложил использовать [GUID](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID), в качестве уникальных значений.

Мой вариант с использованием rand() и рекурсии:

```
<?php
function makeUniqFolderName($path)
{
    $folderName = $path . "/" . sprintf("%04d", rand(1, 1000));
    if (is_dir($folderName)) {
        $folderName = makeUniqFolderName($path);
    }
    return $folderName;
}
mkdir(makeUniqFolderName("/tmp/foo/bar"), 0777, true);
```